# htaccess - how to add automatically "http://servename.com/" to all internat urls?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

In latest Chrome browser adds prefix "https://servername.com/" to internal my links. Not with "http://", but exactly "https://". And it causes a problem, because on these adresses (starting with "https") there's no content, it's on "http".

I don't want to add SSL certificate (also, I can't). Instead, I want to redirect all links starting with backslash, like "/here_is_target_link" to explicity redirect to its http paths: "http://servername.com/here_is_target_link".

Also, I can have on my page some direct links (like http://servername.com/here_is_link) and I want them to be intact.

Help anyone?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Why should this solve my problem? It's not only on my computer, by on every Chrome browser, when you open that page. Also on mobile Chrome.